# Dynamic Button not calling click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

I have a asp Table in my page and I create its contents from the code-behind. For this particular TableRow I need to create a multiline textbox and a button, when I click a button I save the textbox content into my DB. But my click function isn't getting called. Here's my code:

```
ContentPlaceHolder cont = new ContentPlaceHolder();
HtmlGenericControl br = new HtmlGenericControl();
HtmlGenericControl br2 = new HtmlGenericControl();
TextBox texto = new TextBox();
Button btnSalvarTexto = new Button();
btnSalvarTexto.ID = "btnSalvar";
btnSalvarTexto.Click += new EventHandler(btnSalvarTexto_Click);
btnSalvarTexto.CssClass = "botao";
btnSalvarTexto.Text = "Salvar";
cont.ID = "Placeholder";
texto.ID = "TextBoxObs";
texto.Width = 300;
texto.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
texto.Rows = 3;
br.InnerHtml = "<br><br><div style='width:300px;background-color:#fff;padding:15px;'>";
cont.Controls.Add(br);
cont.Controls.Add(texto);
cont.Controls.Add(btnSalvarTexto);
br2.InnerHtml = "</div>";
cont.Controls.Add(br2);
td2.Controls.Add(cont);
tr2.Cells.Add(td2);
TablePrecos.Rows.Add(tr2);
```

The event handler:

```
void btnSalvarTexto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Update command here, this function doesn't even gets called, so it doesn't matter what it does
}
```

What's wrong with my code? I've put a breakpoint in the `btnSalvarTexto_Click` function and it never reaches it.

EDIT: Ok, the function wich creates these controls is called CriarCapa, it's called in `Page_LoadComplete` like this:

```
 protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
 if (!IsPostBack)
 {
    CriarCapa();
 }
```

So yeah, I'm testing to see if it's not a postback.

Comment: Where is the control creation code? In Page Load? Is that code block called on every postback?

Comment: Post your `Page_Load` code.

Comment: I call it in the `Page_LoadComplete` only on the first enter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to recreate the button on each page load, because it is being wiped out by the button being clicked and causing a post back.

The button causes a post back, which triggers the `Page_Load` event in the page lifecycle before the actual event handler. Since the button is dynamically created, when the page load happens and your code only builds the dynamic content the first time through, the button is not created nor is the event handler wireup for the click event.

Comment: I'm going to quibble a bit with your language, just because it should help Thiago think about it correctly. Nothing is being "wiped out." ASP recreates the page object on each postback, because ASP is stateless. ASP creates the page object from the aspx file, and then hydrates it with information from the POST (including the ViewState). It uses that info to decide if any event handlers should run. If the code that creates the button isn't run on each POST, there is no button to fire the event.